# dnsmasq: serve DHCP on bridge whose IP is out of subnet

Tags: dnsmasq

I want to use dnsmasq to serve DHCP on a Linux bridge:

- only one VM is expected to connect to the bridge
- the VM's MAC is fixed
- VM should get a static IP via DHCP
- the bridge itself should not take any IP from the subnet (but it's ok for it to take a dummy IP like 169.254.x.x/16)

Below is the config I'm using:

```
port=0
bind-interfaces
interface=br0
dhcp-range=10.0.0.2,static,255.255.0.0
dhcp-host=52:54:00:d1:82:c4,10.0.0.2,infinite
```

The problem is, it seems to me that I have to give the bridge an IP within the subnet (like 10.0.0.1/16) to make the whole thing work. If I don't specify any IP on the bridge, or just specify a dummy IP (like 169.254.x.x/16), my VM would not get any IP from DHCP.

So is there any dnsmasq option/flag I can leverage with to make this work? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you add the output of `ip add dev br0`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging into dnsmasq's source code, the shared network feature seems to work for me. The added `shared-network=...` line did the trick, though I'm not 100% sure this is the correct/safe way to go.

```
port=0
bind-interfaces
interface=br0
shared-network=br0,10.0.0.101
dhcp-range=10.0.0.101,static,255.255.0.0
dhcp-host=52:54:00:d1:82:c4,10.0.0.101,infinite
```

Answer (score 0):

DHCP does require local subnet communication between client and server.

Initial DISCOVER, OFFER, REQUEST and ACK is done between 0.0.0.0 and 255.255.255.255, but the server does respond from its own IP. Any renewal is however unicast directly to server IP.

So what you want to do is a bit out of spec, with that said it might be possible with an extra level of DHCP relay.

Comment: I can actually make it work with the help of a [Golang DHCP lib](https://github.com/insomniacslk/dhcp). But the way I use it is a bit hacky and may not cover all corner cases. Just wondering if dnsmasq has a decent way to support this scenario.